# Pentaho not retaining the log and temp files

Tags: pentaho, netezza

I am running a pentaho ETL kettle transformation(.ktr) to load data from a source db2 database into a destination netezza database.
When I run the transformation, I specify the directory to store the log files and temp .txt files. But after the transformation finishes, these files are no longer there, so I guess pentaho is cleaning them up. IS there a way to retain these files?

The other problem is that I am getting a sql exception while the transformation step is inserting into netezza like this:

```
error
2013/10/30 14:13:17 - Load XXX_TABLE_NAME - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.netezza.internal.QueryExecutor.getNextResult(QueryExecutor.java:279)
```

No further details are there. How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

That seems like an issue with pentaho. Is there no way to generate a trace of what it's doing in the transformation ? are you sure it's reading data ? what happens if the target is not netezza ?

If you've got access to the netezza appliance, there are a few options, all in the documentation. off the top of my head:

- look in the current queries view while it's running
- enable query history logging (requires admin access + restarting the instance)
- check the pg.log file in /nz/kit/log/postgres/ (logs all queries by default)